# How can I add hexadicimal numbers

Tags: java, hex, addition

How can I add the following hex value using java method

```
A28904048E
```

as

```
A2 + 89 + 04 + 04 + 8E
```

to get the value as 1C1

Comment: Are you asking about splitting a string into 2-character chunks, or parsing those chunks as hex, or adding numbers together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it that way:

```
        String hashTwo="A28904048E";
        long sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<hashTwo.length();i+=2){
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(""+hashTwo.charAt(i)+hashTwo.charAt(i+1),16);
        }
        System.out.println(Long.toHexString(sum));
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Hexadecimal values are integers so you can add them simply like you add integers.

In your case you first need to split your string into group of 2 like this:

```
"A28904048E".split("(?<=\\G.{2})")
```

and then you can parse them as hex and finally add it.